# Product of a sequence that includes 0

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that you had a finite sequence of numbers which includes 0. Does this mean that product of the sequence will always equal zero?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You can try proving this using induction. Another option could be using commutativity and associativity of multiplication. Basically rearrange the sequence so the $0$ is on the front $0 \cdot (a_1 \cdot ... \cdot a_n)$. Since $0 \cdot x = 0$ for any $x$ the product of the sequence has to be $0$.